# Duplicate class com.google.android.aidl.BaseProxy found in modules jetified-google-pay-client-api-1.0.0-runtime.jar

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies, implementation

Code was working properly for whole day. And suddenly getting below error logs without changing any code.Duplicate dependencies are showing in app. Also tried to get tree structure of all used libraries in app.

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.aidl.BaseProxy found in modules jetified-google-pay-client-api-1.0.0-runtime.jar (google-pay-client-api-1.0.0.aar) and jetified-installreferrer-1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.android.aidl.BaseStub found in modules jetified-google-pay-client-api-1.0.0-runtime.jar (google-pay-client-api-1.0.0.aar) and jetified-installreferrer-1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.android.aidl.Codecs found in modules jetified-google-pay-client-api-1.0.0-runtime.jar (google-pay-client-api-1.0.0.aar) and jetified-installreferrer-1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.android.aidl.TransactionInterceptor found in modules jetified-google-pay-client-api-1.0.0-runtime.jar (google-pay-client-api-1.0.0.aar) and jetified-installreferrer-1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1)
```

Below are the dependencies in my app level gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'  //Loading Image
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'pro.appus:zoom-splash:1.0.0'//--------------Splash Animator---------------------
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)' //------Facebook Integration---------
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.chabbal:slidingdotsplash:1.0.2'

    //---------------Circular ImageView------------------------
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //---------------------Crop Library------------------------
    implementation 'com.oginotihiro:cropview:1.0.0'

    //-------------For Video Upload --------------------------
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
    // reactive
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.10'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.github.worker8:radiogroupplus:v1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'

    //-----PayU Money-----------
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.6.0'

    //implementation'com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:7.5.1'
    implementation'com.payu.networking:payu-core-networking:1.1.0'  
    implementation'com.payu.payuanalytics:payuanalytics:1.1.1'      
    implementation'com.payu.upisdk:upisdk:1.0.2'                    
    //implementation'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.6.0'
    implementation'com.payumoney.graphics:asset-download-sdk:0.5.0' 


    //------CashFree--------------
    implementation files ('libs/cashfreesdk-1.4-release.aar')
    implementation files ("libs/google-pay-client-api-1.0.0.aar")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0'


    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.5'

    //----------------Firebase Implementations------------------------------------------------------

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.2'


    //----------------------Vimeo dependencies-------------------
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.4'
}
```

Spent almost 2 days to resolve these dependency issue, but no success. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Please find which library is using install referrer and Kindly update the library.

```
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1.1'
```